# How to (is it possible to) set property of user control from outside?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SearchResultsBox">
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SearchResults}" SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
             Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle1}"
             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SearchItemContainerStyle}"
             Background="{StaticResource DefaultBackground}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <local:Forecast_SearchResults_ListView_Data/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
</UserControl x:Class="SearchResultsBox">
```

I want to be able to reuse this listbox and just slap on a new  datatemplate from the external context:

```
<local:SearchResultsBox>
    <DataTemplate = {ForecastDataTemplate}/>
</local>
```

And it will put this DataTemplate into the ListBox.ItemTemplate property. Is this even possible? If so, how? If not, is there another way to achieve a similar effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use as follows

```
<local:SearchResultsBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ForecastDataTemplate}" />
```

and you can wire up the property to the underlying ListBox

eg

add a name to listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="list" ... />
```

add a property wiring

```
public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
{ 
    get { return list.ItemTemplate;}
    set { list.ItemTemplate = value;}
}
```